# How to display latest data according to branch from logged in user using mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is my full code to display the latest data in the database, but its not according to branch for the current user login in the system.
How do I display the latest pdf data according to the branch user logged in the system.

```
public ActionResult Index(string ImageType = "", int id = 0)
{
    using (WWLIS dc = new WWLIS())
    {
        eventFile item = dc.eventFiles.OrderByDescending(u => u.fileID).ThenByDescending(u => u.branchID).FirstOrDefault();
        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(item.image);
        var imgsrc = string.Format("data:application/pdf;base64,{0}", base64);
        if (ImageType != null)
        {
            ViewBag.ImageSrc = imgsrc;
            return PartialView("PDFVIEW");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.ImageSrc = imgsrc;
            return PartialView("IMAGEVIEW");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We really need more information to help. What fields are in eventFiles? What's the id getting passed in?

Comment: eventFiles is the name for DBcontext                                                    public DbSet<eventFile> eventFiles { get; set; }

Comment: eventFiles is the name for DBcontext                                                    public DbSet<eventFile> eventFiles { get; set; }. I want the code get the latest pdf data entered to the database by fileID and display it by branchID according to the user logged in to the system, but  I dont know how to write it.

Comment: It's okay, I already done it by myself. Thank You for your effort.